# GestureDetector not functioning as expected

Tags: flutter, dart, gesturedetector

I'm trying to enable the functionality of changing the color of the icon once it is pressed, but the `GestureDetector` is not working as expected. How do I fix this?

```
Color maleCardColor = inactiveCardColor;
Color femaleCardColor = inactiveCardColor;

void updateColor(int i) {
  if (int == 1) {
    if (maleCardColor == inactiveCardColor) {
      maleCardColor == activeCardColor;
    }
  } else {
    maleCardColor == inactiveCardColor;
  }
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        updateColor(1);
                      });
                    },
                    child: Contain(
                      c: maleCardColor,
                      w: IconWidget(
                        i: FontAwesomeIcons.mars,
                        s: 'MALE',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Contain(
                    c: femaleCardColor,
                    w: IconWidget(
                      i: FontAwesomeIcons.venus,
                      s: 'FEMALE',
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your updateColor() to this.

```
 void updateColor(int i) {
    if (i == 1) {
      if (maleCardColor == inactiveCardColor) {
        maleCardColor = activeCardColor;
      }
    } else {
      maleCardColor = inactiveCardColor;
    }
  }
```

and if you want single selected colour. male or female, then do it like this and add **GestureDetector** in female Icon Widget and pass **updatColor()**, any value except 1.

```
  void updateColor(int i) {
    if (i == 1) {
      if (maleCardColor == inactiveCardColor) {
        maleCardColor = activeCardColor;
        femaleCardColor = inactiveCardColor;
      }
    } else {
      femaleCardColor = activeCardColor;
      maleCardColor = inactiveCardColor;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     if (maleCardColor == inactiveCardColor) {
         maleCardColor == activeCardColor;
      }
```

You had to change from == to = .. I mean you are not
comparing but assigning.